# ClassCastException thrown when creating a javax.sound.sampled.Clip

Tags: java, swing, javasound, java-module

I want to play sound in a Java Swing application.  I referred to https://www.baeldung.com/java-play-sound and modify like this:

module-info.java

```
module sound {
    requires java.desktop;
}
```

The source files are in the same folder [mydomain]/desktopproject/sound.  There is a Swing JFrame with a JButton, when I press the button the following snippet runs until the last line throws a ClassCastException:

```
audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
    new FileInputStream(new File("/path-to-my.wav"))
));
AudioFormat audioFormat = audioStream.getFormat();
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
Clip audioClip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
```

The exception message is like this:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectSDL
   cannot be cast to class javax.sound.sampled.Clip
   (com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectSDL
   and javax.sound.sampled.Clip are in module java.desktop
   of loader 'bootstrap')
```

I am not sure where the problem is.  I use openjdk version "11.0.20" 2023-07-18 and when I ran `java --list-module`, I got:

```
java.desktop@11.0.20
```

Comment: Instead of `DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);` can you please try with `DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, audioFormat);`?

Comment: Yes that works, thank you.  If you put that as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation ([here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.Info.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.Class,javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat))), the first argument of the `DataLine.Info` constructor you are using is:

> the class of the data line described by the info object

Then, according to the documentation of `AudioSystem`'s `getLine` method ([here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getLine(javax.sound.sampled.Line.Info))):

> Obtains a line that matches the description in the specified `Line.Info` object.

Also, `DataLine.Info` is a `Line.Info`, hence I assumed that the documentation of `getLine` applies to `DataLine.Info` as well. My assumption results mainly from OOP inheritance and trust in the implementation.

Finally, the error is a `ClassCastException`, which indicates (and states) that the returned object by `getLine` was not of type `Clip`.

From the docs and the observation of the error and if the assumption is true and after searching similar usages to get inspired, one can maybe conclude that the first argument of `DataLine.Info` constructor should be the type of object returned by `getLine`. This is why I suggested in the comments of the question to try the following solution to this:

Change the following line of code:

```
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
```

to:

```
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, audioFormat);
```

in order to obtain a instance of `Clip` (which is a `DataLine`, which is a `Line`).

I didn't try it and I am not really familiar with `javax.sound.sampled` package (hence a comment initially), but since you reported it worked, I figured it is an answer and wrote it here.

Answer (score 3):

I don’t know why people continue to believe the Baeldung guy is an expert on Java.  He is not.

You can just replace these lines:

```
AudioFormat audioFormat = audioStream.getFormat();
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
Clip audioClip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
```

with this:

```
Clip audioClip = AudioSystem.getClip();
```

That [getClip()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getClip()) method has been available since Java 1.5, so there is no excuse for a 2023 article that claims to aid Java programmers overlooking it.

Comment: So `audioFormat` will be determined when opening the `AudioInputStream` with the `Clip`? Then this is a better answer.

Comment: Yes.  Feel free to write a test program to prove to yourself that it works.  (Or I can add such a program to my answer;  it’s pretty short.)